# ElasticSearch configuration for 3-node cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

ElasticSearch is used as a cache for PostgreSQL database to avoid a lot of joins and speed up my application selects.

Initially everything is stored at single large server (32GB RAM): webapp, nginx, postgresql, celery, elasticsearch.

Now I have 2 additional smaller nodes which is not used at all (only for additional storage with nbd-server).

So I have:
- 1 Large node with ES. About 12-16GB of RAM is available for ES.
- 2 small nodes with 8 GB RAM. Everything is free for ES.

All 3 nodes have SSD and same CPU.

Later I will add more 8GB nodes (as storage + ES).

What will be the best way to built ES cluster on this 3 nodes? Should all of them be data/master nodes? Or it will be better to use large node as a master and 2 small as

Comment: What do you mean by same CPU? Same number of cores or the same producer?

Comment: Yes, absolutely the same CPU (manufacturer, cores, etc.)

Comment: I thought about setup main server (with webserver, etc.) as master node and this 2 servers as data nodes. Will it be right setup?

Comment: No :-). The data nodes are more loaded than a master node. The master node needs less resources than the data nodes. I would go with both master/data for all three nodes, but I'm a bit concerned that you have other stuff on the larger node. The other stuff will use CPU cycles as well. If your nodes are not heavily loaded you can have other things on those machines, otherwise you will always have a more loaded node.

Comment: Yeah, thats why I thought about this setup. For small cluster I thought 2 data nodes will be fine for all searches, etc. But also we can reduce load for master node and add resources for other things like webserver, celery, scrapers.

Comment: I just set `master: false, data: true` on this 2 nodes and reverse for master node. also `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1` on master node. Thats right for thing I want?

Comment: If somehow you lose the master or lose the master connectivity to the other two nodes, your cluster will not function anymore.

Comment: Hmm. So you recomend to setup all 3 nodes as master and data for this small cluster?

Comment: Kinda' yes :-). Also, when you query/index the/into cluster, send the requests in a round-robin fashion to all the nodes.

Comment: Master + Data setup becomes interesting with 5 nodes :)